# Issue on using policy gradients with Tensorflow to train a pong game agent

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to understand how policy gradient works and build a pong game agent from sketch using Tensorflow but it seems doesn't work. I am not sure if I have some misunderstanding for the policy gradient. Here I post my code with explanations.

Create placeholder first for holding the input frame obtained from the environmant

```
input_frame = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [380*400, None], name='input_frame')
```

Define the parameter for the simple network and the model

```
W1 = tf.get_variable(name='w1', shape=[200, 380*400],initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(seed=2))
b1 = tf.get_variable(name='b1', shape=[200, 1], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())
W2 = tf.get_variable(name='w2', shape=[3, 200],initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(seed=2))
b2 = tf.get_variable(name='b2', shape=[3, 1], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())

def build_model():
    L_1 =tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(W1, input_frame), b1))
    L_2 =tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(W2, L_1), b2))

    Y = tf.nn.softmax(L_2, axis=0)
    return Y
```

Discount reward function

```
def discount_rewards(r):
  discounted_r = np.zeros_like(r)
  running_add = 0
  for t in reversed(range(0, discounted_r.size)):
    if r[t] != 0: running_add = 0
    #https://github.com/hunkim/ReinforcementZeroToAll/issues/1
    running_add = running_add * gamma + r[t]
    discounted_r[t] = running_add
  return discounted_r
```

Build the model

```
Y = build_model()
```

Sample operation

```
sample_op = tf.multinomial(logits=tf.reshape(Y, (1, 3)), num_samples=1)
Y_action = sample_op - 1    #Move up: -1, stay still: 0, move down: 1
```

Routine initialisation

```
global_step = tf.train.get_or_create_global_step()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
```

Retrieve next frame from the environment with cropping

```
next_frame = my_pong.get_next_frame().T[pong_game.SCOREBOARD_HEIGHT + 6 : pong_game.WINDOW_HEIGHT, 0 + pong_game.PADDLE_THICKNESS:pong_game.WINDOW_WIDTH - pong_game.PADDLE_THICKNESS].reshape(380*400, 1)
```

Get the observation by subtracting the current frame and the last frame

```
observation_ = next_frame - last_frame
action_ = sess.run(Y_action, feed_dict={
        input_frame: observation_})
```

For each frame, get the reward from the environment by inputting the sampled action, and append the episode memory.

```
done_, reward_ = my_pong.paddle_2_control(action_)
episode_menory.append((observation_, action_, float(reward_)))
last_frame = next_frame
```

If one side obtains 21 point, the done_ value will be true and start the training process

First discount and normalise the reward

```
if done_:
    obs, lab, rwd = zip(*episode_menory)
    prwd = discount_rewards(rwd)
    prwd -= np.mean(prwd)
    prwd /= np.std(prwd)

    obs_reshape = np.squeeze(obs).T
```

Build a one hot label using the sampled action in the episode

```
    lab_one_hot = tf.one_hot(np.squeeze(lab)+1, 3, axis=0)
```

Cross entropy loss. One hot labels are the sampled action while logits are the output of the model. **(I am not sure if this is correct or not)**

```
    cross_entropy = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels=lab_one_hot, logits=Y)
```

Define the cost function by multiplying the processed reward "prwd" and the cross entropy lost

```
    cost = cross_entropy * prwd
```

Define the optimizer and start training

```
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)
        train_op = optimizer.minimize(cost)

    _, cost_ = sess.run([train_op, cost], feed_dict={input_frame: obs_reshape})

    episode_menory = []

    print("Episode %d finish! Cost = %f" % (episode, np.sum(cost_)))

    episode += 1
```

I run this program on my Titan X device for a weekend but it seems no improvement for the performance. The cost is outputting randomly sometimes negative sometimes positive. And I don't know how to measure the model preferences from the outputted cost value. I wonder which part that I miss or mistaken. Thank you very much.

I post the full code here: https://github.com/ivonchan0414/pg_pong

Comment: Very well done first question on SOF. congrats.  Now .. to see if I can actually help ..

Answer (score 0):

You have a rich (/complex) training and feedback setup here. I can not pinpoint an error by simple casual examination.

A way to isolate the issue might be to follow a typical pipelines debugging and verification process:

- instrument the individual stages of your pipeline by saving the intermediate results
- validate the intermediate results:  you will then narrow down where the behavior diverges from the expected

In addition:

- start with an input dataset for the testing that has a well known expected behavior.  You will likely *not* see that in the output initially: but at least you will be sure that the cause were not due to *data* that your model can not readily handle.